# Regular expression Proof

Tags: regex, regular-language, proof

Can I get a hint on how to prove that for any regular expressions A and B

A(BA)* = (AB)*A

I tried to do it with induction but I get stuck after the base case,

Answer (score 3):

It works well with induction.

Base case is `*` being zero repetitions:

```
A (BA)^0 = A = (AB)^0 A
```

For one repetition, notice you can break `AB` down into `A`, then zero repetitions of `BA`, then `B`:

```
A (BA)^1 = A B (AB)^0 A = ABA = AB A = (AB)^1 A
```

This can be generalised: you can always strip off the first `A` and last `B` out of any `(AB)^n` and find `(BA)^(n-1)` inside: `AB AB AB` is the same as `A BA BA B`.

```
A (BA)^n = A B (AB)^(n-1) A = (AB)^1 (AB)^(n-1) A = (AB)^n A
```